# How to consolidate different methods in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have this operation of filling missing values.

```
mean_impute = df['column'].fillna(value=df['column'].mean())
median_impute = df['column'].fillna(value=df['column'].median())
mode_impute = df['column'].fillna(value=df['column'].mode())
```

Is there any way on how to replicate this line of code in a much cleaner way, is there a way to `loop` on this or to create a `function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be best practice (because of `eval`) but you could avoid to repeat yourself by storing your results in a dictionary:

```
impute = dict()

for fun in ["mean", "median", "mode"]:
    impute[fun] = eval(f"df['column'].fillna(value=df['column'].{fun}())")
```